# Can Robot Models for simulations be used in all ROS versions?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having trouble in simulating robots in gazebo as most models use ROS indigo in their documentaries as well as in Ros.org domentaries; basically all robots I've encountered so far.

Such as (fetch robot):

> sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-fetch-gazebo-demo

which prints out this Error:

> indigo-fetch-gazebo-demo

Reading package lists... Done

> 

Building dependency tree

> 

Reading state information... Done

> 

E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-fetch-gazebo-demo

so I tried just changing indigo to my current version (Melodic_

> sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-fetch-gazebo-demo

but the same error prints out:

> 

melodic-fetch-gazebo-demo

> 

Reading package lists... Done Building

> 

dependency tree        Reading state

> 

information... Done

> 

E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-fetch-gazebo-demo

Am I doing anything wrong?

or the model just hasn't been updated for melodic? (if so, what robot models are for melodic?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305685/can-robot-models-for-simulations-be-used-in-all-ros-versions?/) by [JerelVelarde](https://answers.ros.org/users/38025/jerelvelarde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue you are running into is not one of whether the simulation works, but whether the simulations have been released as debian (ie: `.deb`) packages for a specific OS and ROS release.

Seeing as you tagged this `melodic`, I'm going to assume you are running Ubuntu Bionic.

On a Bionic machine you cannot install packages built for ROS Indigo -- that version of ROS just isn't supported on Ubuntu Bionic (see [REP-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#indigo-igloo-may-2014)).

And since `fetch_gazebo_demo` (the *ROS package*) has not been released for Melodic, trying to install it using `apt-get` will also not work: the *debian package* simply doesn't exist (see [status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=fetch_](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=fetch_)).

---

Now as to the question of whether simulations (and I'm assuming Gazebo simulations here) created for ROS Indigo will work on ROS Melodic: the question is more subtle than that. ROS Indigo installed Gazebo 2.2 by default (see `REP-3` again). ROS Melodic comes with Gazebo 9 (see [REP-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#melodic-morenia-may-2018-may-2023)).

There are quite a few changes between these two versions of Gazebo (and about 6 major versions), both in terms of the API and ABI as well as the dynamic behaviour of the simulator and the things that are simulated (Gazebo 9 has become a lot more realistic in its simulation than Gazebo 2 ever was).

So even while things (ie: plugins or Gazebo models) may work (ie: load) perhaps after fixing some incompatible things, the behaviour they exhibit in Gazebo 9 vs Gazebo 2 may be so different that we can no longer state that they "work".

Note that I'm not referring to the Fetch packages that you mention -- I don't know whether they work -- but wanted to address your question in general.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JerelVelarde](https://answers.ros.org/users/38025/jerelvelarde/) on 2018-10-13**:
Thanks, had a hint that thsi would be the issue. however I'm having issues with models for melodic; for example the fetch robot, I found this bot under the melodic robots category but in the documentations the instructions are all for indigo :(

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-14**:
That would be something to "complain" about to Fetch. They are the ones who release those packages. I don't own one of those robots, so I don't know, but you could look around to see whether someone forked their pkgs to make them compatible with Melodic.